# Is there any chance I could get my phone touchscreen working again?

Tags: screen, touchscreen, water-damage, google-pixel-4a

I have a Pixel 4a smartphone and some water mixed with disinfectant fell on it yesterday. I turned off the phone and wipe it within 30 seconds and let it off for about 30 minutes.
Now the middle part of the touchscreen won't respond to touches eventhough the rest of the phone seems fine. I removed the sim card tray, it doesn't seem to have any signs of humidity. Is there any chance I can fix the issue whithout unmounting the phone or do some expensive repairs?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: You can power off the device for a few minutes and the boot it up again or perform a vectors reset. If this doesn't help the problem is most likely a defect hardware.

Comment: I think it is unfortunately. It's close to two days and still no answer from the middle part of the touchscreen.